# I'm looking for a command to resize the console

Tags: c, visual-studio, console-application

is there any way to enlarge the console with a single / few commands?

What I work with:
Visual Studio 2019 Professional
C++ Console Application

Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single command: SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx() and is documented at [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolescreenbufferinfoex)

This info live inside the  struct

```
typedef struct _CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX {
  ULONG      cbSize;
  COORD      dwSize;
  COORD      dwCursorPosition;
  WORD       wAttributes;
  SMALL_RECT srWindow;
  COORD      dwMaximumWindowSize;
  WORD       wPopupAttributes;
  BOOL       bFullscreenSupported;
  COLORREF   ColorTable[16];
} CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX, *PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX;
```

`dwSize` is the size of the buffer and the `SMALL_RECT` controls the part of the buffer that is on-screen at the moment

The default for the buffer is 9001 lines so `SMALL_RECT` could be called `NOT_SO_LARGE_RECT` :)
[image: VS2019 Command Prompt properties, as an example]

Note that as many console API calls **YOU MUST SET** `cbSize` to the size of the structure prior to calling the function

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-reference] This is the documentation for the console functions and structures, the Console Bible